# Error using classloader to load groovy class

Tags: java, groovy, classloader

I am attempting to load a groovy class by name using a classloader, and the class fails to load in the case that the class has a reference to a static inner class in another class.

Inside my groovy class I have the following:

```
def classLoader = getClass().classLoader
try { 
    classLoader.loadClass( "com.test.TestClass" )
} catch(Throwable e) { 
    Sigil.logger.error("Error loading class: $it >> ${e.message}", e)
}
```

In the above, my groovy file TestClass has a static inner class inside it, that extends a static inner class of another file. When I try to run the above code I get the message:

```
ERROR [05 Aug 2013 06:53:28,851] (invoke0:?) - Error loading class: com.test.TestClass >> startup failed:
unable to resolve class UserValidity.Validator 
 @ line 85, column 5.
       public static class Validator extends UserValidity.Validator{
       ^

1 error
```

Has anyone come across any problems dealing with static inner classes and class loading in groovy before?  The classes all compile correctly and unit tests run etc.   I would have thought that when I try to load the class TestClass explicitly in my classloader, it would also load the other necessary classes from the source tree as needed?

---

**UPDATE:**

Here is a snippet of the class that is failing to load:

```
class TestClass{

    //... Other normal class stuff here

    public static class Validator extends UserValidity.Validator
        @Override
        def validate(u) {
            def result = super.validate(u)
            if(!u.valid ){
                result += [isValid:false]
            }
            result
        }
    }
}
```

And this fails as it says it cannot resolve the reference to the UserValidity.Validator, which is also pretty simple:

```
class UserValidity {

    //normal class stuff here

    public static class Validator {
        def validate(u){
            //do validation stuff
            result
        }
    }
}
```

Both are just regular groovy classes.

---

**UPDATE 2:**

If I extract the static inner class `UserValidity.Validator` out in to a standalone class, and just extend that with the static inner class in `TestClass` then it appears to work, so definitely seems to be some issue with the parent of the inner class being another inner class

Comment: Is it a Java class you're loading?  Can you post an example of a class that fails to load?

Comment: @tim_yates have updated with extracts from the classes - all just regular groovy

Comment: Odd...  seems to work if I pre-compile the `UserValidity` and `TestClass` classes with `groovyc`

Comment: @tim_yates so it doesn't work for you if you don't pre-compile them?

Comment: Nope, I get the same as you... Think this might be http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GROOVY-4287